# Electric field of a dipole from superposition and from multipole expansion

Tags: electrostatics, dipole, multipole-expansion

This question came in my physics test:

> Charge density in a one dimensional space is given by $\rho=Q[\delta(x-x_0)-\delta(x+x_0)]$. The electric field due to this charge distribution at point (2$x_0$,0,0) is given as $\overrightarrow{E}(x)=n\frac{Q}{\pi\epsilon_0x_0^2}\hat{x}$. The value of n (rounded off to three decimal places) is ___ ?

My answer is 0.223(rounded off from 0.222...) but the professor says that the answer is 0.125! To obtain my answer I directly used the formula of electric field of a point charge and superposition principle. But the professor says that since the monopole term of this charge distribution is zero, the question cannot be solved using two monopoles(like I did) but from the formula of field of a dipole, because the monopole term won't contribute to the field.

Is this correct? I mean, his argument is certainly correct but my method seems right too! I guess that the professor is using the wrong formula for a dipole's field. The most correct formula is after all from the multipole expansion with the monopole term neglected. But he uses the formula $\overrightarrow{E}(\overrightarrow{r})=-\nabla(\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\overrightarrow{p}\cdot\hat{r}}{r^2})$, which is true only for an ideal point dipole, which does not apply to our dipole.

So which is correct: n=0.222... or 0.125?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct; this is almost a textbook example of a situation where superposition is appropriate. The dipole formula assumes that $x \gg 2x_0$, and if the question asked for the field at $x = 20x_0$ instead, your answers would be nearly the same.

The dipole term is part of a Taylor expansion of the generic potential $$\Phi(\mathbf x) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int{\frac{\rho(\mathbf x')}{\left|\mathbf x - \mathbf x'\right|}d^3x'}$$ in the denominator. The infinite Taylor series looks like $$\Phi(\mathbf x) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \left[\frac{q}{r} + \frac{\mathbf p \cdot \mathbf x}{r^3} + (\text{quadrupole term)} + (\text{octupole term}) + \ldots \right]$$

(your professor uses $\mathbf{r}$ and not $\mathbf{x}$). Anyway, your professor is right that the monopole moment ($q$, the total charge) is zero. But for an $r$ that isn't large, higher-order terms (like the octupole moment) will not be negligible. As far as I know, your answer is the most correct.